# Can I install a 256gb SSD from a late 2010, early 2011 MacBook air 13 inch (A1369) into my late 2010 11 inch MacBook Air (A1370)?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

The 11 inch MacBook air did not ship with or offer a 256gb SSD, only 64gb and 128gb. However the 13 inch from late 2010 did ship with a 256gb SSD.

Is the 256gb SSD from the 13 inch MacBook air (A1369 I believe) compatible with the 11 inch MacBook Air (A1370) from the same late 2010 time period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The drives are the same physical dimension. There will be no issue with it being recognized.